# Getting error 'NotImplementedError("That compression method is not supported")' when extracting zipfile in python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I have read through the Python documentation about zip files and watched a couple of videos, but everything didn't work. I'm using Kali Linux, so that the password has to be encoded in bytes.

Here is my code, with which I have tried:

```py
import zipfile
import string
import traceback

def try_function(zip, pwd):
    try:
        zip.extractall(pwd=pwd.encode())
        print("Yes")
    except TypeError:
        print("No")


z = zipfile.ZipFile("test.txt.zip")
pwd_local = "abc"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try_function(z, pwd_local)
```

But I always get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ZipWorker.py", line 22, in <module>
    try_function(z, pwd_list)
  File "ZipWorker.py", line 11, in crack
    zip.extractall(pwd.encode())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1633, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1686, in _ 
extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1559, in open
    return ZipExtFile(zef_file, mode, zinfo, pwd, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 797, in __init__
    self._decompressor = _get_decompressor(self._compress_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 698, in 
_get_decompressor
    _check_compression(compress_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 678, in 
_check_compression
    raise NotImplementedError("That compression method is not 
supported")
  NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm using python3.9.

Comment: How did you create the .zip file? What compression method did you use?

Comment: The only issue I got with your code is the call to [`extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall), which has 3 arguments and you need to use keyword args if you only pass password. It should be `zip.extractall(pwd=pwd.encode())`. Other than that, your code works fine, no errors. So it's probably related to how you created the zip file.

Comment: Check with other zip files. If you got the zip file somewhere else, try creating one yourself.

Comment: I created the zipfile with the standard zipfile creator on kali linux. I also tryed it on windows with 7zip, but it didn't work (I tried it without keywords). But i will try it with the these. The thing is, the program how it is now  works fine in python3.

Comment: Ok, i tried this with the keywords, but it gives me the same error as before. I also edit the code above to pwd=pwd.encode().

Answer (score 1):

So I finally find out, why the code above doesn't work. 
When you are creating a zipfile with for example 7zip, this zip file will be encrypted.
But the encryption isn't in bytes, it's encrypted in the hashes: AES-256 or ZipCrypto.